# Check if string contains the same pattern

Tags: php

How can I check if a string has a specific pattern like this?

XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX

*4 alphanumeric characters then a minus sign, 4 times like the structure above.*

What I would like to do is that I would like to check if a string contains this structure including "-".

I'm lost, can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Example code:

```
$string = "5E34-4512-ABAX-1E3D";

if ($pattern contains this structure XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX) {
echo 'The pattern is correct.';
}

else {
echo 'The pattern is invalid.';
}
```

Comment: Must `XXXX` be the same in every part? Or is `1234-asdf-7890-asg1` also valid?

Comment: regular expressions are your best friend.

Comment: @Sumurai8 No they can be different, like the example you posted.

Comment: @Calimero could you provide me with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expressions

```
<?php
$subject = "XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX";
$pattern = '/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}\-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}$/';
if(preg_match($pattern, $subject) == 1);
    echo 'The pattern is correct.';
} else {
    echo 'The pattern is invalid.';
}
?>
```

`[a-zA-Z0-9]` match a single character

`{4}` matches the character Exactly 4 times

`\-` matches a escaped hyphen

Comment: You don't need to escape hyphen at this position ;)

Answer (score 0):

use preg_match :

`$ok = preg_match('/^([0-9A-Z]{4}-){3}[0-9A-Z]{4}$/', $string)`

And if you want to consider lowercase characters, use :

`$ok = preg_match('/^([0-9A-Z]{4}-){3}[0-9A-Z]{4}$/i', $string)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It was a tie between you and Ashish

Answer (score 0):

With a perl regexp :

```
$string = "5E34-4512-ABAX-1E3D";

if (preg_match('/\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}/',$string)) {
    echo 'The pattern is correct.';
}
```

Comment: \w is not good because it includes underscore. Moreover, there is no start-string (^) and end-string characters ($)

Comment: @fred727 that's for the OP to decide.